# Get the real clicked element tag name for once with jquery

Tags: jquery, click

I want my click function to run for all elements and in that i wanna get the clicked element tag name.

For a page like this for example,

```
<html>
<body>
  <form>
   <div>
     <input type="text">
     <textarea></textarea>
   </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

if i run this js code

```
$("*").live('click',function(evt) {
    alert(evt.target.tagName);      
});
```

and click on the textarea, it alerts "TEXTAREA" for 5 times because it has 4 parents.

Where to fix?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [jQuery's `stopPropagation()` method](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/):

```
$("*").live('click',function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    alert(evt.target.tagName);      
})
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HFaLV/).

Answer (score 0):

[***jsFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/s43rt/)

Events in JavaScript naturally bubble up to their parents (especially when using *deprecated* methods like `live` which require events to bubble up to the top-level of the DOM to be handled).

To prevent multiple alerts, verify that the current element is the same as the targeted element:

```
$("*").live('click',function(evt) {
    if (this == evt.target) {
        alert(evt.target.tagName);
    }      
});
```

Comment: This works too but isn't .stopPropagation() is a better practice since in this code, function is going to run for the times of number of the parents anyway?

Comment: No, I don't think `stopPropagation` is a better solution. There's a reason events bubble by design in JS, since a user can't see the DOM when they're using your page. If you disable bubbling of all click events, and the user clicks the paragraph text within a `div`, your click handler for the `div` won't fire, and the user won't have the experience they're expecting. You should always be wary of disabling  the default JS propagation (and of binding handlers to `*`, though that's a different issue).

Comment: Wow, thanks for reminding that. I just ran the fiddle with the `stopPropagation()` method with an extra click function for divs to change their bg color and it doesnt work if i click on the `input` inside the `div`. But if i change it with your `if` statement they all work. Great!